# If statement on every case within switch

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

Is there a way to run a check on a variable in a function on every case without typing it out every time?

Javascript

```
function htmlParse(type) {
    var returnString = "";
    $('#drag-drop > .draggable').each(function() {
        var item = $(this).attr('id');
        switch(item) {
            case 'bread-top':
                returnString += '<html>';
                if (type == 'string')
                    returnString += '\n';
                break;
            case 'bread-bottom':
                returnString += '</html>';
                if (type == 'string')
                    returnString += '\n';
                break;
            case 'turkey':
                returnString += ''+
                            '   <body>\n'+
                            '       Your website content goes here.\n'+
                            '   </body>';
                if (type == 'string')
                    returnString += '\n';
                break;
        }
    });
    return returnString;
}
```

In this example I want to run `if (type == 'string')...` on every case in the switch without having to actually type it out each time.

Maybe it's because it's late, but I can't think of a way to do this without building each case from an array.

Comment: Put it after the `switch`?

Comment: Side note: **Strongly** recommend using `{}` consistently, even if (at the moment) the block only has a single statement in it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - It should be noted that I need the line break after each case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put it *after* the `switch`:

```
var item = $(this).attr('id');
switch (item) {
    case 'bread-top':
        returnString += '<html>';
        break;
    case 'bread-bottom':
        returnString += '</html>';
        break;
    case 'turkey':
        returnString += '' +
            '   <body>\n' +
            '       Your website content goes here.\n' +
            '   </body>';
        break;
}
if (type == 'string')
    returnString += '\n';
```

If you need non-matching cases not to do it, add `default` and use a flag:

```
var item = $(this).attr('id');
var flag = true;
switch (item) {
    case 'bread-top':
        returnString += '<html>';
        break;
    case 'bread-bottom':
        returnString += '</html>';
        break;
    case 'turkey':
        returnString += '' +
            '   <body>\n' +
            '       Your website content goes here.\n' +
            '   </body>';
        break;
    default:
        flag = false;
        break;
}
if (flag && type == 'string')
    returnString += '\n';
```

Comment: This is it. For some reason I couldn't even comprehend to put the check after the switch but within the .each() loop. This is why I should sleep and look again in the morning before asking dumb questions. Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Since your are doing the same thing for all the cases you can move it out of the switch-case

replace

```
return returnString;
```

with

```
return type === "string" ? returnsString +"\n" : returnString;
```

Be aware that if you don't initialise type somewhere else, the condition will always fail and if returnString can ever be anything than a string you should probably find a better name for it.